# Check if differents columns are null

Tags: python, pandas

Below are my 2 df

```
df1

QTY 
3000
201
NaN
100

df2

QTY
NaN
203
50
905
```

The aim is to create a function which gives the expected output by using a function.

```
df1
QTY    SUM
201    404
100    1005
```

The expected output should use something like that

```
   if df1.QTY | df2.QTY is not None:
       df1.SUM = df1.QTY + df2.QTY

    else: 
      pass
```

I have tried it but it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'bool'
```

Thanks for anyone helping!

Comment: _I have tried it but it gives me the following error:_ Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message. There are a few problems with the line `if df1.QTY | df2.QTY is not None:`, be careful.

Answer (score 2):

One could simply add the dataframes by -

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'qty': [3000, 201, np.nan, 100]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'qty': [np.nan, 203, 50, 905]})
df1['sum'] = df1['qty'] + df2['qty']
```

and then filter out the nulls by using -

```
df1 = df1.loc[~df1['sum'].isnull()]
print(df1)
```

**Output:**

```
     qty     sum
1  201.0   404.0
3  100.0  1005.0
```